# Google Play Services - dex error on inclusion

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, ibm-mobilefirst, dex

I have a running basic hybrid app which I want to enhance with native Google mapping functionality. The pre-requisite for this would be to include Google Play Services library in the project.

```
The problem is including the Google Play Services lib gives a dex error :
[2015-07-31 17:23:31 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
[2015-07-31 17:23:31 - projectAndroid] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

The IDE is eclipse & am using IBM MobileFirst to build the hybrid app.

I only need the mapping functionality from the library, but the play services jar includes a lot more, really more.

The suggested methods are proGuard and using multi-dex.

The Multi-dex option really makes the app heavy, which I'm really trying to avoid. The app is intended to be super light.

Just wondering if someone out there has a stripped down version of the Google Play Services lib that can be reused or if can specify which packages are sufficient enough to show maps.

For maps too, I intend to have a map fragment showing a marker using lat-long. That's it.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: Google provides [selective Google Play services dependencies](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split), but they only work with Android Studio/gradle based builds (as [Eclipse support has been stopped](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to go for MultiDex with your application as total number of methods you got now exceeds 65536 limit single dex file can handle (it's all because of dependencies, especially Google Play Services). This issue is discussed in official documention and the workaround is pretty simple, so go and apply [what's described here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) and you should be fine.

You do not want to go for any stripped version of your dependencies. It is not solving your problem, especially Google is not providing any. The problem is dex file limit and the solution is to go for multidex. any other path may cost you more time wasted for repetitive fixes in future that it would be worth.

Answer (score -1):

You can get only the play service library you need.

For use the maps you only need to include

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
```

Instead of:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

Take a look in those links for more info http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html and https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup